# Minus characters displayed as line

Tags: abap

In our SAP addon, many `-` signs in a sequence are displayed as a line.
Is there a way to display them as individual minus signs?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Give us a piece of code, that is used for list output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`FRAMES OFF`](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/en/abapformat.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_6@6@) addition of either the `WRITE` or the `FORMAT` statement.